Showing the return in BlueJ, using the Code Panel
When you are using BlueJ and create an object into the object bench and then execute a method with an return, this red window pops up, returning the return.
If you use the code panel, create an object there and use the code panel, the return window wont show up.
I know, I could use "System.out.print" to print it out, but I was just wondering, if there is any way to make this red return window pop up, whilst in the code panel?
I typed into the code panel:
class.inspect();

In this the inspect method should return an specific integer, which it probably did, but didn't show
